# Segmentation fault when reading variables in pointed function

Tags: c++, c, c++11, memory-management, bazel

I have the following pieces of code: (Note: the codes are simplified and changed a lot as I can't share the data)

`exercise.cpp`

```
#include "some_api.h"

extern "C" int extension_init(func_t*, VExtension*);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    VExtension ve;
    extension_init(&func, &ve);
    return 0;
}
```

`some_api.h`

```
bool func(int const& a, void* const& b, VExtension* const& v)
{
    std::cout << a << b << std::endl;
}
```

`api.h`

```
typedef int (func_t)(int c, void* p, VExtension* v)
```

`file.cpp`

```
#include "api.h" // this is included implicitly

extern "C" int extension_init(func_t* F, VExtension* v)
{
    intptr_t ver = 7;
    F(1, (void*)ver, v);
}
```

So, when `F` is called `func` is called from `some_api.h`, but `Seg Fault` appears when trying to output the values `a` and `b`.
Static analyzer gives the following error message:

```
ASAN:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==15==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000001 (pc 0x55d6dbe48ca2 bp 0x7fff79dbf320 sp 0x7fff79dbf300 T0)
==15==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==15==Hint: address points to the zero page.
    #0 0x55d6dbe48ca1 in func(int const&, void* const&, VExtension* const&) some_api.h:279
    #1 0x55d6dbefe697 in file.cpp:809
    #2 0x55d6dbe5373a in main exercise.cpp:123
    #3 0x7f9c65393b96 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
    #4 0x55d6dbd49839 in _start (//...)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: some_api.h:279 in func(int const&, void* const&, VExtension* const&)
==15==ABORTING
```

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  The function signatures do not match.  Notice that `int (func_t)(int c, void* p, VExtension* v)` and `bool func(int const& a, void* const& b, VExtension* const& v)` are not the same thing.

Comment: Why does `some_api.h` define an implementation for that method as well? That seems like a mistake.

Comment: If this is a C method then you can't use references.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, it is also strange that it works, but when I change types appropriately, I'm getting the compile error.

Comment: @DavidHovsepyan Can you the changed code and what error it gives you?

Comment: @NathanOliver error: invalid conversion from 'bool ( * )(int, void*, VExtension*)' to 'bool ( * )(const int&, void* const&, VExtension* const&)' [-fpermissive]
   extension_init(&func, &ve);

Comment: @DavidHovsepyan: Use backticks (``) around code in comments to prevent misinterpretation

Comment: Your parameters don't match.  You can't use a function that takes references and give it to a function pointer that does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Corrected code could work

If `func_t` would be defined using the same signature as `func()`, everything would be fine, since the arbitrary value of b is never dereferenced:

```
typedef bool (func_t)(int const& a, void* const& b, VExtension* const& v);
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/pasdtC).

### But your code can't, so there's something fishy going on here

Your code seems to compile, at least judging from the runtime trace you've displayed.  But according to the snippets you've posted, the code should not compile at all.  So I suspect that your different headers managed to create a dangerous mix, using different definitions from `func_t` in different compilation units.  If this is the case, you would be in the world of undefined behavior.

For instance the return type `int` doesn't match return type `bool`.  But much more fatally, in `func_t` the parameters are plain values, whereas in `func()` they are all references.  So if the compiler was tricked, the calling convention used by the caller of `func()` would be incompatible with the calling conventions used by `func()`, thus causing invalid memory accesses (most probably --but this woud be implementation dependent-- the generated calling code would send value arguments, but the generated receiving code would expect these parameters to be pointers to values and try to access the pointed memory locations, which would be invalid).

### Additional remark

Now, I'm not a language lawyer, but it's also interesting to see a function using a C calling convention (`extern "C"`), using parameter and return types that do not exist in C (i.e. bool and references).

### Additional insights

Looking at the [assembly code generated](https://godbolt.org/z/AVBOHq) for `extension_init` on one compiler using the corrected definition of `func_t`:

```
lea rdx, [rsp+8]           ; load effective address of third paramvalue
lea rsi, [rsp+24]          ; load effective address of second param value
mov QWORD PTR [rsp+24], 7  ; initialize value 
lea rdi, [rsp+20]          ; load effective address of first param value
mov DWORD PTR [rsp+20], 1  ; initilize value
call rax
```

If [using your original definition](https://godbolt.org/z/JDos-W), the code generated looks differently:

```
                ; the third value was left out by the global initializer
                ;  but it was previously set with an LEA to load the effective 
                ; address of the struct. 
mov esi, 7      ; pass the second value
mov edi, 1      ; pass the first value
call rax
```

Comment: You're right, I have found that I have different .h files with different function pointer declarations, so I put here wrong declaration. Actually, I found the right declaration and because of that the code compiles, but as you mentioned it is undefined behavior due to different `func_t` declaration in different translation units.